# perl script consumes 100% cpu

Tags: regex, linux, perl, gdb

I have a perl script which does some mysql connections to fire select query.
I used DBI perl module to do the same.

Sometimes it consumes 100% cpu and does nothing. I got gdb backtrace of the live process while it was consuming 99% to 100% cpu.

```
#0  0x0000003990a7c680 in memcpy () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003992ae6e27 in Perl_regexec_flags () from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
#2  0x0000003992a922d5 in Perl_pp_subst () from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
#3  0x0000003992a8a39e in Perl_runops_standard () from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
#4  0x0000003992a37ecc in perl_run () from /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
#5  0x00000000004017bc in main ()
```

what should i do ? (I am using CentOS release 5.8 (Final) kernel-2.6.18-308.el5)

Comment: It looks like it's processing a regex.  Can something like http://search.cpan.org/~jjore/App-Stacktrace-0.08/bin/perl-stacktrace tell you where in the Perl code it's stuck?

Comment: Well, you look through your code, possibly searching for a `s///` substitution that is bound to very large data, or that can backtrack very badly. A normal backtrace is too low-level to provide useful data (this here tells us only which Op was running).

Comment: Please include the code which is executing, especially the regex.

Comment: thnx for the reply JOSH, I tried but it says `warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO`

Comment: First, using 100% CPU is not a problem. It's actually a good thing. That means there is no wasted CPU. It seems to me you're actually complaining that a call is taking too long. What do you want us to do about it? We can't provide alternatives since you didn't say what you are trying to do. We can't help you debug it, since you didn't provide anything to debug.

Comment: Reposting this as a comment: Based on the scant information provided so far, my first guess would be that you've got a regex guilty of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a regexp processing could take a forever, even on moderate amount of data.

Let say you have a regexp like this:

```
my $data =~ s!.*findit:(.+)!$1!gis;
```

This regexp do the same but it is much faster:

```
my $data =~ s!\A.*findit:(.+)\z!$1!is;
```

Comment: *“Sometimes a regexp processing could take a forever”* Incorrect: I think to recall that after 50 operations that do not consume characters, the Perl regex engine aborts. Also, the position in the string cannot be decreased except through backtracking. Therefore, every regex terminates. However, a regex can be written in such a way that excessive backtracking takes case (e.g. with many `?` quantifiers, or greedy matching). Your example does not demonstrate this, and can be written as `s/\A.*(?i:findit):(?=.)//s` if you want to avoid an unneccessary captures.

Comment: thnx user1126070, it was very useful.

Comment: I had this problem in a production script, so it was the case at least in the past several years ago (early 5.8, late 5.6)